# I don't have the good version of Ruby in VsCode with Flutter and Pod

Tags: ruby, xcode, flutter, dart, apple-m1

So, when I run `ruby -v` in the terminal in Mac M1, I have the good version of Ruby which is ruby 3.2.0 that I installed with rbenv. The problem is when I run pod outdated in VsCode in my ios folder in flutter I get this

[image]

It uses my Ruby version pre-installed on my mac m1 which is the folder usr/lib/ruby and is an old version : 2.6

Also, I can't run my app with "Flutter run" I have lot of problems with everything related with pod (when I add packages like cloud_firestore). Maybe it's because of that, if someone can help me ?

Comment: This sounds like a vs-code configuration issue, is very unlikely to be because you’re using m1 hardware, and seems to have nothing to do with xcode. I’d suggest altering the tags accordingly, or editing your question to explain the relevance of the tags you chose.

Comment: There is a lot of problem between M1 and cocoapods

Comment: Perhaps, but the problem you’ve described is vs-code defaulting to the ruby which ships with the OS rather than the one you’ve installed. I’m not a vs-code user, but that sounds like a PATH configuration issue. In other editors/IDEs, similar problems are sometimes solved by adding a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) line to the script, or by starting the editor from a terminal window so it picks up your shell environment settings. Regardless, I suspect you’ll get more joy with a vs-code tag than an Xcode one.

Comment: Most of the time this means that VS Code is either 1) loading the wrong shell (e.g., your default shell is ZSH and VS Code is trying to load Bash) or 2) not loading your shell profile (e.g., it runs a non-interactive terminal and skips your `.zshrc` where you tell it how to find the installed version of Ruby). You should post the exact steps you take in VS Code to cause this error, e.g., "I install <some VS Code extension> from <this URL> and then open the command palette and run <some command> and I expect to see <some output> but instead I see <some invalid output>." **Be specific**.